# python: how to generate a bitmap?

Tags: python, bitmap

What's the easiest way to generate a bitmap using Python?

Text support would be nice but not required.

(On Mac, I was trying to use Quartz through Python, but Snow Leopard seems to have broken its functionality. Therefore I've decided to look for a solid, simple, cross-platform solution that won't break each time the OS is updated.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/):

*"The Python Imaging Library (PIL) adds image processing capabilities to your Python interpreter. This library supports many file formats, and provides powerful image processing and graphics capabilities."*

I'm not a Mac person so I can't help with Mac specifics, but I do know it works on the Mac.